# How to use papa-parse-angular2

Tags: json, angular, csv, data-conversion, format-conversion

Want to use [papa-parse-angular2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papa-parse-angular2) to convert CSV to JSON. Didn't find any example so I do it like this.

> app.module.ts

```
import {CSVService} from 'papa-parse-angular2';
@NgModule({
providers: [
CSVService, ...
```

> xx.component.ts

```
constructor( private csvService: CSVService, ...
private x1() {
    let file = ...;
    this.csvService.parse(file, {
        complete: function(results) {
          // take results.data
        }
      });
```

No build issue. But when run it, got following error.
[image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at CSVHandler.guessHeaders (vendor.bundle.js:105749)
    at CSVHandler.formHeaders (vendor.bundle.js:105734)
    at CSVHandler.setHeaders (vendor.bundle.js:105761)
    at vendor.bundle.js:64297
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (vendor.bundle.js:137052)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.bundle.js:4532)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (vendor.bundle.js:137051)
    at Zone.run (vendor.bundle.js:136812)
    at NgZone.run (vendor.bundle.js:4401)
    at vendor.bundle.js:64293
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (vendor.bundle.js:4247)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (vendor.bundle.js:14620)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (vendor.bundle.js:14569)
    at Subscriber._next (vendor.bundle.js:14509)
    at Subscriber.next (vendor.bundle.js:14473)
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (vendor.bundle.js:15308)
    at EventEmitter.emit (vendor.bundle.js:4221)
```

No idea on how to fix. Or other libs to convert CSV to JSON in angular 4? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-papaparse

Answer (score 7):

You could use [ngx-papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-papaparse).

First install the library:

For Angular 6 ([docs](https://alberthaff.dk/projects/ngx-papaparse/docs/v3/introduction)):

`npm install ngx-papaparse --save`

*There is also a version for [Angular 2/4](https://alberthaff.dk/projects/ngx-papaparse/docs/v1/introduction) and [Angular 5](https://alberthaff.dk/projects/ngx-papaparse/docs/v2/introduction).*

Then import it into your module (doesn't have to be your AppModule):

```
import { PapaParseModule } from 'ngx-papaparse';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    PapaParseModule
  ]
})
```

Parsing CSV:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Papa } from 'ngx-papaparse';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private papa: Papa) {
        let csvData = '"Hello","World!"';

        this.papa.parse(csvData,{
            complete: (result) => {
                console.log('Parsed: ', result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can also parse a file, instead of a string. Just replace `csvData` with the file.

Disclaimer: I created the library.

Comment: file meaning csv file location/path?

Comment: @Euridice01 File can be either a path, a file-object or a string. Please refer to the docs. They should cover it (see download-attribute); https://alberthaff.dk/projects/ngx-papaparse/docs/v3/parsing-csv/options :-)

Comment: But it doesn't cover local resource file inside the project

Comment: It has to be a file that is accessible to the browser. If the file resides inside a public directory, simply enter it's HTTP-path, and set `download = true`.

Alternatively, you can add a file form-input and supply that file to Papa Parse.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [papaparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse).

```
import * as Papa from 'papaparse/papaparse.min.js';
```

To use

```
onUpload(file: File) {
   Papa.parse(file, {
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log("Finished:", results.data);
     }
   });
}
```

However, one downside is you won't get any type definitions of papaparse

Comment: TypeDefinitions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/papaparse. Better use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-papaparse

Answer (score 2):

Install [papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse) and [@types/papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/papaparse). This would enable type definitions for IDE intellisense.

Then, you could import entire papaparse module

```
import * as Papa from 'papaparse'
```

or specify required imports as

```
import { parse } from 'papaparse'
```

This approach is recommended over third-party wrappers, as they are not updated as frequently or have limited community effort behind them.

Answer (score 0):

Import PapaParser as mentioned below:

```
import * as Papa from 'papaparse/papaparse.min.js';
```

then use like:

```
private x1() {
 let file = ...;
  Papa.parse(file, {
  header: true,
  skipEmptyLines: true,
  complete: (results) => {
    let parsedData = results.data; 
  }
})
```